# Share video to Instagram on IOS with react-native-share

Tags: ios, react-native, instagram, react-native-ios

I'm using "rn-fetch-blob", "react-native-fs" and "react-native-share" to share video to instagram.
Video is downloaded from server, stored in cache, then path provided to shareOptions.

On Andrid works perfectly but on IOS post in Instagram have black preview screen.
I know that Instagram takes first frame from video to make preview and my video haven't any black frames.
I suppose it's something wrong with "react-native-share" library, but i can't understand what is the problem

Here is the code I`m using

```
RNFetchBlob.config({
fileCache: true,
appendExt: "mp4" })
   .fetch("GET", data.video)
   .then(async res => {
    const path = await res.path()
    const shareOptions = {
     url: path,
    }
    try {
      await Share.open(shareOptions)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

React-native-share doesn't work well on iOS.
Use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share on iOS and react-native-share on Android